# Solving recurrence similar to Catalan number recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations, catalan-numbers

Today i was solving a dynamic programming problem that is matrix chain multiplication and i come up with a recurrence, i tried for n=4 but :(.

How can I solve this recurrence? It is similar to the Catalan number recurrence.

$$T(n)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n−1} T(k)T(n−k) & n\ge2\\ 1 &n=1
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Alizter could you plz tell  me how to edit math eq. here?

Comment: I would recommend editing the question with your thoughts and anything you have tried so that it can gain more attention. [Reference for MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: see wikipedia :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Answer (score 2):

This is actually just the Catalan recurrence shifted by one; $T(n) = C(n-1)$.

Comment: @ Michael could you please elaborate more?